# How to fix this? (There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first)

Tags: sql, visual-studio

```
Public Sub chartall(ByVal chart1 As Object)
    conn()
    Dim str As String = "SELECT department as 'DEPARTMENT', COUNT(CASE WHEN voterstatus = '1' THEN 1 END) AS 'VOTED', COUNT(CASE WHEN voterstatus = '0' THEN 1 END) AS 'NOT YET VOTED' FROM tblvoter GROUP BY department"
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(str, myconnection)
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Try
        While dr.Read
            chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY(dr.GetString("Course"), dr.GetInt32("COUNT(CASE WHEN voterstatus = '1' THEN 1 END)"))
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code. i just want to put data on a chart.

Comment: which line are you encountering the error? Why are you doing cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() after the exception?

Comment: ensure you are closing the datareader once done. I'd recommend a Using block https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement to ensure that resources are properly closed including both the datareader and connection. Also as a previous commenter suggested, don't re-execute the cmd in the catch block.